# Is this node grounded?

Tags: current, jfet

I'm investigating a circuit with transistors. Below is part of the circuit where a JFET has been approximated with its g-parameters. The circuit continues to the left and right but that isn't relevant.

[image]

The current over I1 is \$g_mu_{gs}\$ where \$u_{gs}\$ is the voltage difference between V1 and V3. From the circuit, it looks like no current would flow through R2, making V3=0. Is this correct? Would this mean that \$I_1 = g_mu_{gs} = g_mV_1\$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Ohm's Law, we would write:

$$I_{R2} = \dfrac{V_3 - 0}{R_2} = 0A$$

But, this implies that

$$V_3 - 0 = 0V \rightarrow V_3 = 0V $$

Intuitively, or in words, we have a "dangling resistor", i.e., one end of the resistor is not connected.  Since the current through must be zero, the voltage across must be zero and, since the connected end is at 0V, the unconnected end is at 0V.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if no current flows through R2, then both ends sit at the same potential.